# calculate the average value of a function f(t) across the interval from a to b

Tags: calculus

[image]
Can anyone please solve this question step by step for me.

Comment: What specific part are you struggling with? Are you unable to determine the function to integrate? Unable to complete the integration?

Comment: You have taken the time to scan the problem, what have you tried? Where are you stuck exactly? Do you know how to define mean value of a function?

Comment: Oh and by the way, a rectified sine wave is simply $|\sin (t)|$...

Comment: hint: When you stretch or compress this function horizontally, will the average value change? Think about the effect of stretches on the period as well as on the area under the curve. What happens when you stretch a rectangle horizontally? What happens to the height of the rectangle? the length? the area?

Comment: i am struggling with completing the integration

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the sine wave has a period of $6$ here, so the function is
$$v(t) = \Bigg|\sin\Big(\frac\pi3 t\Big)\Bigg|$$
The task is now to find
$$\frac13\int_0^3 \Bigg|\sin\Big(\frac\pi 3 t\Big)\Bigg|\;\mathrm dt$$
where you can drop the absolute value because the integrand is nonnegative.

Comment: there is a plot that my lecture did using sin2 which put the wave on a interval of 0 to 0.5. is there any way i can find out what sin to put to get an interval of 0 to 3

Comment: @collins Well $\sin(k\pi t)$ has a period of $\frac2k$ in $t$, so $k = \frac2{T}$ where $T$ is the period. Now in your case $T=6$, note that $\sin(x)$ is zero twice per period.